# Sistema de GRID bootstrap - col-xs-X não reconhece largura

Tags: html, bootstrap, front-end, grid, layout-responsivo

Estou estudando bootstrap, e ao formular o sistema de GRID a col reconhece os valores LG, MD, SM, mas não reconhece o XS solicitado. Quando redimensiono o navegador para tamanho mobile ele sempre coloca a div solicitada em tamanho 12 (full).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Bootstrap Bill Turner</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
    <link href="css/estilo.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">  
</head>   
<style>
    .c{
        background-color:aquamarine;
        border-right:1px solid black;
    }
</style>
<body>
    <div class="container">

        <div class="row">
            <div class="c col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-6 col-xs-1">
                esp
            </div>
            <div class="c col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-6 col-xs-1">
                esp
            </div>
            <div class="c col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-6 col-xs-1">
                esp
            </div>
            <div class="c col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-6 col-xs-1">
                esp
            </div>

        </div>

    </div>
    <script src="js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script> 
</body>
```

Ao redimensionar para mobile,ele apresenta o seguinte layout:

[Navegador redimensionado para resolução mobile](https://prnt.sc/h126dt)

Alguém para me dar uma luz sobre o que estou fazendo de errado?

Um print com o código completo, e as três formas de visualização:[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]Codigo completo e 3 formas de visualização Como podem ver, tudo da certo, menos na COL XS. (Não printei a LG pois não tive espaço no mesmo print)

Comment: Qual a versão do *Bootstrap* você está utilizando ?

Comment: Estou usando a 4.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lendo a [documentação](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#grid-options) você vera que houve uma alteração, ficou mais simplificado em vez de `col-xs-N` agora você pode apenas `col` ou `col-N`, veja abaixo:

Nesse exemplo, criamos *4* colunas informando no atributo *class* o valor `col`, veja elas estão na mesma linha porque o valor foi dividido entre si.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
         <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
        <style>
            .c{
                background-color:aquamarine;
                border-right:1px solid black;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="c col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-6 col">Esp 1</div>
            <div class="c col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-6 col">Esp 2</div>
            <div class="c col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-6 col">Esp 3</div>
            <div class="c col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-6 col">Esp 4</div>
        </div>
    </div>
        <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-vFJXuSJphROIrBnz7yo7oB41mKfc8JzQZiCq4NCceLEaO4IHwicKwpJf9c9IpFgh" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-alpBpkh1PFOepccYVYDB4do5UnbKysX5WZXm3XxPqe5iKTfUKjNkCk9SaVuEZflJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

> Por algum motivo o *Snippet* não funciona aqui no *SOpt* mas coloco a *Print* e pode testar que funciona.

[image: Usando col]

Nesse outro exemplo informamos um valor *N* para `col`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
         <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
        <style>
            .c{
                background-color:aquamarine;
                border-right:1px solid black;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="c col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-6 col-2">Esp 1</div>
            <div class="c col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-6 col-2">Esp 2</div>
            <div class="c col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-6 col-8">Esp 3</div>
            <div class="c col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-6 col-12">Esp 4</div>
        </div>
    </div>
        <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-vFJXuSJphROIrBnz7yo7oB41mKfc8JzQZiCq4NCceLEaO4IHwicKwpJf9c9IpFgh" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-alpBpkh1PFOepccYVYDB4do5UnbKysX5WZXm3XxPqe5iKTfUKjNkCk9SaVuEZflJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

A Primeira e a Segunda coluna ira ocupar 2 espaços na *Grid*, e a Terceira ira ocupar 8 espaços, e por fim a Quarta coluna que ocupara 12 espaços na *Grid*.

> Por algum motivo o *Snippet* não funciona aqui no *SOpt* mas coloco a *Print* e pode testar que funciona.

[image: Usando col-N]

#### Referência

- [Grid options](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#grid-options)

Answer (score 0):

Olá, do jeito que esta deveria funcionar. Veja seu codigo rodando. 
https://codepen.io/mjunior/pen/zEQPpb?editors=1100

Você talvez não tenha especificado a metatag viewport no seu html.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
```

Comment: Exatamente, era pra estar funcionando =/ . Mas o porque não está é o X da questão. Eu usei a metatag viewport da seguinte forma: "<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1>". Vou tentar acrescentar o codigo fornecido, mas honestamente não acho que seja o motivo pelo qual ele não reconhece a COL XS. Mais tarde posto os resultados

Comment: Adicionei conforme exibido no ultimo print, o restante da linha de codigo. E não deu resultado algum.

Answer (score 0):

Você tem que atentar para esse redimensionamento, no sentido em que está mesmo redimensionando para mobile, porque você pode estar redimensionando para tablet, onde o tablet usa a classe sm.

Além do mais, tem uma classe 'c' antes das medidas. Isso está correto? Você realmente tem essa classe (em maiúscula)?

```
<div class="C col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-6 col-xs-1">
 esp
</div>
```

[Segue artigo que pode ajudar.](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_grid_examples.asp)

Comment: Testei o codigo em 4 resoluções, que seriam relativas às 4 cols possiveis, LG, MD, SM e XS, o print enviado é referente à resoluçao reconhecida como XS. E sim, a classe C está correta, no codigo mesmo descreve o objetivo da mesma, apenas para alterar a cor do background das divs, e tornar a visualização mais clara.